# Nodes not joining cluster in Elasticsearch 5.1 cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, distributed-computing

I want to setup a cluster with 3 nodes(1 master, 1 client and 1 data node) with Elasticsearch 5.1.1. I have connected 3 windows 10 machines through a wireless network and edited the `elasticsearch.yml`file of each node as follows:

**master node:**

```
cluster.name: searchapp

node.name: es-master-01
node.master: true
node.data: false
node.ingest: false

network.host: 192.168.1.3

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["es-client-01", "es-master-01",  "es-data-01"]
```

**client node:**

```
cluster.name: searchapp

node.name: es-client-01
node.master: false
node.data: false
node.ingest: true

network.host: 192.168.1.4

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["es-client-01", "es-master-01",  "es-data-01"]
```

**data node:**

```
cluster.name: searchapp

node.name: es-data-01
node.master: false
node.data: true
node.ingest: false

network.host: 192.168.1.2

discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["es-client-01", "es-master-01",  "es-data-01"]
```

When I try to run elasticsearch on the master node it gives the following output
[image]

The nodes are not joining the cluster and I tried replacing the hostnames to IPs but still the nodes aren't joining.

Comment: I think your machine does not resolve the hostnames for your nodes, did you try `nslookup` the nodes to see that you can successfully resolve the names?

Comment: I can ping the machines to one another but haven't tried the nslookup. Can I do it on a LAN?

Comment: Can you `ping` the names and it successfully get the desired response?

Comment: Yes I can ping successfully

Comment: When elasticsearch is run on nodes, the nodes are in separate clusters but share the same name (searchapp) and do not recognize other nodes

Comment: Just to be on the safe side, can you add all the hosts and its ip's to `/etc/hosts` (assuming you're on linux machine) on all machines?

Comment: Am on machines with Windows 10 as I have mentioned on the question

Comment: Ohh sorry for that! Can you add all the hosts and its ip's to `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`?

Comment: Did the above. Now it's working..Thank you

Comment: I'll move it to an answer to help others in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the attached logs, it seems that your `elasticsearch` cluster cannot resolve the host names for the machines.

I suggest to add all of your hosts names to the hosts file so each machine would know how to resolve the host names.

For linux:

```
/etc/hosts
```

For windows:

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
```

Where by default, `%SystemRoot%` means: `C:\Windows`